# Kuala Lumpur Layover KLIA2 from Thailand to India flight

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, transit-visas, kuala-lumpur

I am an Indian Citizen travelling to Thailand. On my way back I have 12 hrs of layover (with same airline & PNR) in Kuala Lumpur. Needed to check if I can step out of the airport? If yes, then what are requirements in terms of visa/travel pass?

Answer (score 2):

For Malaysia, if you want to leave the airport, you will need a visa

From TIMATIC :

> > Passengers transiting through Kuala Lumpur (KUL) with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 24 hours. They
> > must:
>
> - arrive at and depart from the same terminal, and
> - stay in the international transit area of the airport, and
> - have documents required for the next destination.

But you qualify for an [e-visa](https://malaysiavisa.imi.gov.my/evisa/evisa.jsp) as an Indian national.

For an RM 105 fee (around 25USD at the time of posting) and reported 6 days for processing, but with reports of it being extremely [unreliable](https://www.tripadvisor.com.sg/ShowTopic-g293951-i7006-k14123102-Malaysia_visa_processing_time-Malaysia.html), make sure to get it early